# Docker composing not working for multiple projects

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a folder structure like below:

```
[Services]
|
+--[IdentityService] (this folder contains Docker & docker-compose file)
|
+--[ProductService]  (this folder contains Docker & docker-compose file)
|
+--[ApiGateway]  (this folder contains Docker & docker-compose file)
|
+--docker-compose.yml
```

Here are my Different Docker files:

**1] ApiGateway - Docker file**

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 9000
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:9000

FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["APIGateway.csproj", "./"]
RUN dotnet restore "./APIGateway.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "APIGateway.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "APIGateway.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
#ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "APIGateway.dll"]
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "APIGateway.dll", "--server.urls", "http://0.0.0.0:9000"]
```

**2] IdentityService - Dockerfile**

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-aspnetcore-runtime AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 9001
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:9001

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-sdk AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["WebApi.csproj", "./"]
RUN dotnet restore "./WebApi.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "WebApi.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "WebApi.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
#ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebApi.dll"]
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebApi.dll", "--server.urls", "http://0.0.0.0:9001"]
```

**3] ProductService - Dockerfile**

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-aspnetcore-runtime AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 9002
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:9002

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-sdk AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Product.API.csproj", "./"]
RUN dotnet restore "./Product.API.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "Product.API.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Product.API.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
#ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Product.API.dll"]
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Product.API.dll", "--server.urls", "http://0.0.0.0:9002"]
```

And my **docker-compose.yml** looks like below:"

```
version: "3"
services:
  api_gateway:
    image: cog/mfp_api_gateway
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Services/ApiGateway/ApiGateway/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8082:9000"
    depends_on:
      - identity_service
      - product_service

  identity_service:
    image: cog/mfp_identity_service
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Services/IdentityService/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:9001"
    depends_on:
      - db

  product_service:
    image: cog/mfp_product_service
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Services/ProductService/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8081:9002"
    depends_on:
      - db

  db:
    image: "mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest"
    environment:
        SA_PASSWORD: "MYPASSWORD"
        ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
    ports:
      - "1433:1433"
    volumes:
      - ./.db:/var/opt/mssql/
      - /var/opt/mssql/data
```

Here, when I run docker files individually, all are building and running properly. But, when I can run outer  **docker-compose.yml**, I'm getting PATH related errors. Do i need to specify relative path in **docker-compose.yml** file?

Comment: Why are you specifying both build and image? It may not know which to use. And yes docker-compose.yml paths are relative (unless starting with a slash), but it looks like you've written them correctly as relative

Comment: Also you should stop specifying context as "."

Comment: @Shardj You mean to say, building them separately and use those images in yaml instead of build command?

Comment: I'd just use docker-compose build, I wouldn't specify an image because you'll just confuse docker compose as it won't know whether to look up the built image or the specified image.

Comment: @Shardj please help me in rewriting my outer yaml file

Comment: `PATH related errors`, what's it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docker commands in your Dockerfile (more specifically `COPY`) are relative to the current docker context.

When you build your images individually, I guess that you run `docker build` from each of your `Services/<service>` directories, which means the context is that particular directory.

When you build them through docker-compose, you are explicitly saying that context is `.`, meaning the directory where your `docker-compose.yml` resides.

Just change the context for the build and you should get the expected result => `context: ./Services/<service>`. You can drop the `dockerfile` declaration as you are using the default name.